# Redirección a una carpeta de mi servidor

Tags: .htaccess, servidor, redirección

tengo esta estructura de carpetas en mi servidor:

```
- App
  - www
    - index.php
- App2
  - index.php
```

Y tengo configurado mi dominio, por ejemplo, `midominio.com` para que apunte a `App -> www`

¿Sería posible que si acceso a través de una url concreta me redirija a la carpeta App2?
Por ejemplo, si entro en, `midomino.com/segundaapp` tire de `App2 -> index.php`

Comment: dependiendo del sistema operativo del servidor podes crear un enlace simbólico `/app/www/segundaapp` -> `/app2`

Comment: No sé exactamente qué SO será pero imagino que Linux. El tema es que solo tengo acceso al FTP del servidor :(

Comment: fijate si te deja [crearlo desde php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php), onda subir y ejecutar un archivo `setup_asdfadfdsaf.php` -> `<?php symlink('/App2','/App/www/segundaapp') ?>` ó tal vez `<?php exec('ln -s /App2 /App/www/segundaapp');?>`

Answer (score 0):

Eso puede depender de como tengas configurado el dominio, es decir, si el dominio apunta a tu hosting y, ahí a directo la carpeta www en app, me parece que no vas a poder a subir mas arriba de www desde el mismo dominio.

Puedes coger un segundo dominio (dominio2), que apunte al otro index (app2) y luego hacer una redirección del dominio1/directorio a dominio2.

Otra opción es cambiar el arbol de forma que:

Dominio
 - app > www
 - app2 > www

Supongo que asi, con una regla de htacces puedes hacer que por defecto entre en app > www pero app2 > www esta a la misma altura con lo cual es mas fácil poder volver.